# NSLevelIndicator - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, progress-bar, appkit, nsprogressindicator, nslevelindicator

How would I be able to use a NSLevelIndicator? I am very new to this so, I don't know much on how to use a progress bar for my application.

Comment: This is too generic to answer.  See <http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html>.  For example, do you need to be told how to make a new Xcode project?  Probably not, but we cannot tell what you do and do not know how to do.

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't use `NSLevelIndicator` for a progress bar. Check out `NSProgressIndicator` instead. It does both progress bars and "spinner" controls. `NSLevelIndicator` is used, for example, to show how full a disk is, or how much battery life is left in your wireless mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain your level of experience.  Assuming you have a window already created in Interface Builder, drag an NSLevelIndicator onto the window, create an outlet to it in your application, and set its value as needed.  If you don't understand any of that, follow [Apple's standard beginners' tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html) and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I be able to use a NSLevelIndicator?

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLevelIndicator_Class/

> how would I use a NSProgressIndicator?

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/

Comment: Ok, I'm just confused on how to set the coding for a NSLevelIndicator.
I have [levelIndicator setIntValue:@"2"];
I know there must be something wrong, but I want to set the level indicator to where it is 2 (green)

Comment: `@"2"` is an NSString, not an `int`.

Comment: Pass an `int`. (If you don't know what an `int` looks like, you should buy a book on C.)